# Prove that for an outer measure $\mu^*$, $\mu^*(E_1\cup E_2) \leq \mu^*(E_1) + \mu^*(E_2)$

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification

This would follow if we can prove the countable subadditivity of outer measure

$$\mu^*(E) = \inf\left\{\sum\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}l(I_n): (I_n:n\in\mathbb{N}) \text{ such that } \bigcup
\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}I_n \supset E \right\}$$

but I would like to prove it only knowing that:

- $\mu^*(E) = \inf\left\{\sum\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}l(I_n): (I_n:n\in\mathbb{N})\right\}$
- $\mu^*(\emptyset)=0$
- $\mu^*(E)\leq\mu^*(F)$ if $E\subset F$

My current (potentially wrong) "proof" doesn't use this three facts.

---

Attempt:

Suppose for a contradiction that $\mu^*(E_1\cup E_2) > \mu^*(E_1) +  \mu^*(E_2)$.

Let $E_1 = E_2 = (a, b)$ for some $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$. Since the outer measure of an open interval is the length of the interval, then by our assumption, $\mu^*(E_1\cup E_2) = \mu^*(E_1) > \mu^*(E_1) + \mu^*(E_2) = 2\mu^*(E_1)$ which is impossible.

Hence  $\mu^*(E_1\cup E_2) \leq \mu^*(E_1) +  \mu^*(E_2)$

---

Two questions:

1. Is my "proof" wrong?
2. How would one prove the subadditivity of the outer measure with only the two facts I listed above?

Comment: Your proof is wrong because you cannot choose $E_1$ and $E-2$. Actually it is not possible to prove this using only the two properties you have listed. Where did you find this question?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, why can I not choose $E_1, E_2$ (or what's stopping me from choosing it)? Why are the two properties insufficient to prove this? I made this question up myself as I was reading my text (but I'm sure some textbooks out there have this as an exercise or something.)

Comment: Once you say 'suppose $\mu^*(E_1\cup E_2) > \mu^*(E_1) +  \mu^*(E_2)$, you  have no control over these sets.. You have to  get a contradiction without assuming anything further abut $E_1$ and $E_2$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, my understanding is that $\forall E_1, E_2, \mu^*(E_1) + \mu*(E_2) \geq \mu*(E_2\cup E_2)$. And so for a contradiction, I just have to produce an example to show that the opposite is not true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the definition of the outer measure (stated in your post) then you can ptrove the subadditivity.Indeed:

Let $\epsilon >0$.

There exist sequences $J_n$ and $I_n$ of intervals such that $\bigcup_nI_n \supset E_1$ and $\bigcup_nJ_n \supset E_2$ and $$\sum_n l(I_n) \leq \mu^*(E_1)+\epsilon$$ $$\sum_n l(J_n) \leq \mu^*(E_2)+\epsilon$$

The intervals $\{J_n,I_n:n \in \Bbb{N}\}$ cover $E_1 \cup E_2$ thus $$\mu^*(E_1 \cup E_2) \leq \sum_{I \in \{I_n:n \in \Bbb{N}\}\cup \{J_n:n \in \Bbb{N}\}}l(I)$$ $$\leq \sum_n l(I_n)+\sum_n l(J_n)$$ $$\leq \mu^*(E_1)+\mu^*(E_1)+2\epsilon$$

But with knowing only the two dotted facts,you cannot.